# Statically linking system libraries, libc, pthreads, to aid in debugging

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, libc, postmortem-debugging

I am trying to avoid the situation described in this Stackoverflow entry:  [Debugging core files generated on a Customer's box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616417/debugging-core-files-generated-on-a-customers-box).  If I compile all the libraries statically will I avoid having to always gather the shared libraries when it core dumps?  I essentially want to be in a situation where I can just load up the core file with gdb and examine the crashed application.

What should I watch out for if I go down the route of statically linking all the libraries we need.  I figure glib and pthreads might cause the biggest problems.

Will Valgrind cease to be useful?  If I load up Valgrind against the binary which has everything statically compiled will it find errors?  Or shall we maintain a binary that isn't statically compiled so Valgrind continues to work.
How about strace?

We crashes quite often as we have a large install base and it is also a legacy application.  Gathering up all the shared libraries is becoming intractable - I need another solution.

Edit: fixed typo.

Comment: You will always need the core file; how else will you be able to examine the contents of memory at the time of the crash.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, thanks.  I meant shared libraries.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the libraries themselves; the debugging symbols are enough (although not *always* available).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If you had bothered to read the linked question, you'll see that your comment is *false*.

Comment: @Employed: Which part of the linked question refutes what I've said?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The answer explains *why* you *do* need the libraries from the target system to analyze the core. If by debugging symbols you meant "separate debuginfo files matching target system's libraries", then your comment is correct (but you didn't make that clear). OTOH, if you meant "debugging symbols for the application itself", then your comment is false.

Comment: I figured that the "themselves" would disambiguate my wording.

Comment: Building on what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said, separate debug info files containing the debug symbols are documented in the GDB manual in "[Section 18.2: Debugging Information in Separate Files](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)".  HTH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I compile all the libraries statically will I avoid having to always gather the shared libraries when it core dumps

Yes.

However, contrary to popular belief, statically linked binaries are *less* portable than dynamically linked ones (at least on Linux).

In particular, if you use any of these functions: `gethostbyname`, `gethostbyaddr`, `getpwent`, `getpwnam`, `getpwuid` (and a whole lot more), you will get a warning at link time, similar to this:

```
Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime
the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking.
```

What this warning means is that *IF* your customer has a different version of glibc installed from the one you used at link time (i.e. different from *your* system libc), *THEN* your program will likely crash. Since that is a clearly worse situation than your current one, I don't believe static linking is a good solution for you.

Comment: Static linking is indeed not a good choice.  Ulrich Drepper - one of the [glibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) maintainers and contributors - makes similar convincing arguments in "[Static Linking Considered Harmful](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/no_static_linking.html)".