# Compiling on CentOS 8 for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, glibc, libstdc++

I am developing a program that will run on both CentOS 8 and CentOS 7 systems. In it, I am using the gethostbyname to resolve DNS names to IP addresses.

To try and make the code portable, I am compiling using the following command:

```
g++ -static stats-agent.cpp -o stats-agent
```

When it compiles I get the following:

```
/tmp/ccVDW5ph.o: In function `main':
stats-agent.cpp:(.text+0x45c): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Now when I move the binary over to the CentOS 7 system and I try and run it, I get the following:

```
stats-agent: dl-call-libc-early-init.c:37: _dl_call_libc_early_init: Assertion `sym != NULL' failed.
Aborted
```

I have checked the glibc, glib-devel and, just incase, glibc-static. The only thing I noticed is version of glibc on CentOS 8 is 2.28 and the version on CentOS7 is 2.17. Could that be causing it? Will I have to compile a separate CentOS 7 and CentOS 8 binary? I am trying to make it portable.

Answer (score 1):

> To try and make the code portable, I am compiling using the following command

Don't. Contrary to popular belief, fully-static Linux binaries are *less* portable -- only guaranteed to work if the *exact* same version of GLIBC is installed at runtime, as the one used during the build. That's what the warning is telling you. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654451/50617).

> Could that be causing it?

It could, and does.

> Will I have to compile a separate CentOS 7 and CentOS 8 binary?

Only if you insist on fully-static linking.

You could build your binary using *dynamic* `libc.so.6` on CentOS 7 (or in a `chroot`, or a docker container, or a VM), and it will work fine on CentOS 8 as well.

Comment: So does that mean on the other side, I'd have to install libraries?

Comment: @chris-p-tech No: `libc.so.6` is already installed on every system.