# gdb no symbol table loaded for core file

Tags: gdb, symbol-table

There was a core dump produced at the customer end for my application and while looking at the backtrace I don't have the symbols loaded...

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x000000364c032885 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000364c034065 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x000000364c032885 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x000000364c034065 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

One think I want to mention in here is that the application being used is build with -g option.

To me it seems that the required libraries are not being loaded. I tried to load the libraries manually using the "symbol-file", but this doesn't help.

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: Is this on HPUX or Linux or some other OS?  On HPUX and AIX, you need a few more options to get the symbol table.

Answer (score 10):

> No symbol table info available.

Chances are you invoked GDB incorrectly. Don't do this:

```
gdb core
gdb -c core
```

Do this instead:

```
gdb exename core
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629444/50617) for what you'll likely have to do to get meaningful crash stack trace for a core from customer's machine.

Comment: hey thanks for the rply, Im already using the gdb as suggested earlier.

Comment: Nope, this isn't the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue and later found out that I am missing -g option, Make sure you have compiled the binary with -g.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you run `gdb` with path to executable that does not correspond to the one that produced the core dump.

Make sure that you provide gdb with the correct path.

```
<put an example of correct code or commands here>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: JamesZ: your comment is pointless. The question was: "What could be the possible issue?" and I have provided one of the possible explanations. I am not stating that my answer should be the most seeked one. But as I was searching the web for the exact same error message I stumbled upon this thread. Initially it did not include the correct answer to my question, but it should, as error message is exactly the same. EDIT: I hit enter too fast:)

Comment: @BostjanSkufca indeed, their comment is relevant. Your post doesn't give a solution, so it should better be a comment to the question instead. Or at least it looks like not giving a solution, because it starts with "This happened to me". Seasoned SO users kill such phrases on sight. =)
The idea of SO is to collect knowledge and solutions if form of some instructins, so it's good to clean your posts from your personal experience ) [answer]

Comment: @NickVolynkin thanks for the style edit+comment, much appreciated.

Comment: @NickVolynkin yeah, I've noticed that instructions in form of babysteps are expected here, but otherwise it is considered inter-professional messaging board :)