# no symbol table info avaliable after analysing coredump in gdb

Tags: c++, unix, gdb

I am new to this unix and gdb. I have a coredump file generated.I am using gdb to debug, but there is no meaningful information found. 
I am getting output as

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt full 

Thread 7 (LWP 12190):
#0  0x00007fa2eae29896 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x000000000000019a in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007fa2e9906ce0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

There are 7 seven threads. and for all I am getting the same. I am not getting the way forward to proceed.Please help me. OR please explain me what does this mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gdb no symbol table loaded for core file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935075/gdb-no-symbol-table-loaded-for-core-file)

Answer (score 3):

This means that there is not a symbol table loaded for the coredump. Chances are you invoked gdb directly on the coredump rather than like this:

```
gdb <executable> <coredump>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ya I have invoked gdb directly on coredump. Bec I dont get executable. Their will be a coredump file generated remotely, which I copied and debuged in locally.

Comment: In order to debug the coredump, you need access to an executable built with debug symbols, otherwise the data is meaningless.

Comment: Now, gdb /opt/bin/ core.old.2014 is the command i gave. Which means i gave execuatable rite? even then their is no meaningful data found. I am still getting the same error

Comment: `/opt/bin/` is a directory, not an executable. You need the program which the dump was generated from.

Comment: No in this directory only all the executable are saved. I work on a big code where all the binaries will be saved in this path. so i gave the path followed by coredump name.

Comment: You need to point _directly_ at the program the coredump was generated from, otherwise, how would gdb know where to look for symbols or how to resolve name conflicts?

Comment: Ya I gave correct command.But i end up in same output. Please tel me the way to dig up this problem. Where no stack trace is found. what should i do to get proper info

Comment: Assuming that you are now passing the correct executable to gdb, that executable may not have been compiled with debug symbols (-g).

Comment: Hi Tartan. According to your suggestion, I made the executable compiled with -g. and checked for the coredump. But i got the same output. No changes:(

Comment: Edit your compiler and gdb invocations into your question, that should give me more information.

Comment: For for disturbing you again. And thanks for your reply.Actually i am using cmake then make, so i checked in cmake file and saw i am using -g flag also. Its just my bad luck that their is no back trace

Comment: If you `dwarfdump` the executable do you get any symbols out?

Comment: what will dwarfdump do?sorry i dont know.:(