# gdb bt gives only ??, how can I debug?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, segmentation-fault, gdb

/var/log/message:

```
segfault at 0 ip 00007fcd16e5853a sp 00007ffd98e37e58 error 4 in libc-2.24.so[7fcd16dc9000+195000]
```

addr2line -e a.out 00007fcd16e5853a

```
??:0
```

gdb bt

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fcd16e5853a in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fcd16e5853a in ?? ()
#1  0x000055f2f45fe95b in ?? ()
#2  0x000055f200000080 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fcd068c2040 in ?? ()
#4  0x000055f2f6109c48 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

build with `gcc -Wall  -O0 -g`

How can I debug this, are there more methods?

Comment: Corrupted stack? Use e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar to help you find the problem?

Comment: Do you link with `-g`? Does `gdb` say that debuginfo has been loaded?

Comment: Oh and you don't strip the debug info once you've built the program?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I didn't strip, and don't know why, if I run it use valgrind, it's too slow, so the bug just does not appear.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin yes, linked with -g and debuginfo installed

Answer (score 1):

> gdb bt

Surely that is *not* the command you actually executed.

Most likely you did something like this:

```
gdb /path/to/core
(gdb) bt
```

Don't do *that*. Do this instead:

```
gdb /path/to/a.out /path/to/core
(gdb) bt
```

If you already did invoke GDB correctly, other likely reasons why `bt` did not work:

1. You are analyzing the `core` on a different machine from the one on which it was produced. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629444/50617).
2. You rebuilt `a.out` with different flags. Use the *exact* binary that crashed.
3. You have updated `libc` after the core was produced. Restore it to the version that was current as of when the core was produced.

P.S. This command

> `addr2line -e a.out 00007fcd16e5853a`

makes no sense: the error message told you that the address `00007fcd16e5853a` is in `libc-2.24.so`. The `a.out` has *nothing* to do with that address.

The command you want to use is:

```
addr2line -fe /path/to/libc-2.24.so 195000
```

P.P.S.

> `segfault at 0 ip 00007fcd16e5853a ...`

This means: `NULL` pointer dereference inside `libc`. The most probable cause: not checking for error return, e.g. something like:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/some/file", "r");
fscanf(fp, buffer, sizeof(buffer));  // Oops: didn't check for NULL.
```

Comment: Thanks, the gdb part is correct, I just simplified that. I'll check the libc part NULL check