# What does ?? in gdb backtrace mean and how to get the actual stack frames?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I was trying to learn how to use `gdb` on core dumps.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    return 1/0;
}
```

This is the `gdb` output, when I run `gdb a.out core`:

```
warning: exec file is newer than core file.
[New LWP 3121]
Core was generated by `./crash'.
Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
#0  0x00000000004004fc in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004004fc in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000400500 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f6ea0945b97 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

What are `??` in the backtrace? How can I resolve them?

Comment: It means that the code does not have debugging information.  Either the object file was not compiled with `-g` or the program was not linked with `-g`.  Sometimes, it means that you are looking at code provided by someone else in a library.

Comment: i compiled it with -g option

Comment: Sometimes it means that your program trampled over the stack, corrupting it so much that the debugger cannot make head nor tail of what is there.  A null (0x0000000000000000) pointer is worrying.  The other values look more or less plausible.

Comment: Note that you need `-g` both for each object file and also when linking the program.  Both!

Comment: `warning: exec file is newer than core file` indicates that the executable and the core dump don't match up, which might also explain gdb's failure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those `??` are usually where the name of the function is displayed. GDB does not know the name of those functions and therefore displays `??`.

Now, why is this happening? Depends. GCC compiles including symbols (e.g. function names and similar) by default. Most probably you are working with a *stripped* version, where symbols have been removed, or just with the wrong file.

As [@zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zwol) suggests, the line you see `warning: exec file is newer than core file` is an indication of the fact that something else is going on that you don't show in your question. You are working on a `core` dump file generated by the crashed executable, which is outdated.

I would suggest you to re-compile the program from scratch and make sure that you are opening the right file with GDB. First produce a new `core` dump by crashing the new program, then open it in GDB.

Assuming the following `program.c`:

```
int main(void) { return 1/0; }
```

This should work:

```
$ rm -f core
$ gcc program.c -o program
$ ./program
Floating point exception (core dumped)

$ gdb program core
Reading symbols from program...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 11896]
Core was generated by `./program'.
Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
#0  0x000055d24a4cd790 in main ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055d24a4cd790 in main ()
(gdb)
```

NOTE: if you don't see `(core dumped)` when running the process that means that a core dump was not generated (which leaves you with the old one). If you are using Bash, try running the command `ulimit -c unlimited` before crashing the program.

Comment: Since OP is working with core dumps, they should also know that if they recompile the program after generating a core dump, they need to crash the program again to get a new core dump -- that's what "warning: exec file is newer than core file" means.

Comment: @zwol right, I've added that to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> What does ?? in gdb backtrace mean

It means that GDB has no idea to which code the addresses in backtrace: `0x04004fc`, `0x0400500`, etc. correspond.

> and how to get the actual stack frames?

That depends on *why* this is happening. There are two common scenarios:

1. You are debugging the *wrong* executable.

   One way this could happen is when you compile with optimization, e.g. `gcc -O2 main.c -o crash`, let the program dump `core`, then recompile with debugging (e.g. `gcc -g main.c -o crash`) and try to debug "old" core dump with "new" executable.

   Don't do that. Instead, compile with optimization *and* debugging: `gcc -O2 -g main.c -o crash`.

   P.S. This warning: `warning: exec file is newer than core file` is intended to warn you *precisely* about this case.
2. The other common cause is when you obtain a crash on a production system and try to debug it on a development one (given the addresses which you show this is unlikely to have happened here).

   For that case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629444/50617).

Answer (score -2):

You did not compile with debug symbols - try adding `-g` to the compile line

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem. GCC does not strip executables by default. OP should see the symbol `main()` with or without `-g`.

Comment: Debugging symbols are a *very different thing*. GCC does *not* strip symbols by default. An ELF produced with GCC will have all function symbols and other symbols such as global variables. Those are ***not*** debugging symbols. And no, I am not ok crack.

Comment: @AdrianCornish Marco Bonelli is correct.  There is enough information about the names of global symbols in an unstripped executable, *even if it was compiled without `-g`*, that GDB should have been able to print the name "main" in the backtrace.  (It wouldn't be able to display the arguments, though.)